Slow Wifi on Fedora 39 on Intel Tiger Lake PCH CNVi WiFi adapter
I am using Fedora 39 KDE spin as my daily driver. What has been bothering me since its installation is the poor internet speed over wifi. The Wifi speed received on Windows and my other Smartphones is decent. However, the speed is quite slow on Fedora despite showing a strong signal.
This is the output of the command inxi -Fzxx.
System:
  Kernel: 6.8.4-200.fc39.x86_64 arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc
    v: 2.40-14.fc39
  Desktop: KDE Plasma v: 5.27.11 tk: Qt v: 5.15.12 wm: kwin_wayland dm: SDDM
    Distro: Fedora Linux 39 (KDE Plasma)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: HP product: Victus by HP Laptop 16-d0xxx v: N/A
    serial: <superuser required> Chassis: type: 10 serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: HP model: 88FA v: 88.58 serial: <superuser required>
    part-nu: 4D8K8PA#UUF UEFI: AMI v: F.25 date: 10/04/2023
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 69.2 Wh (100.0%) condition: 69.2/70.1 Wh (98.8%)
    volts: 17.0 min: 15.4 model: HP Primary serial: <filter> status: full
  Device-1: hidpp_battery_0 model: Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 2S
    serial: <filter> charge: 55% (should be ignored) status: discharging
CPU:
  Info: 6-core model: 11th Gen Intel Core i5-11260H bits: 64 type: MT MCP
    arch: Tiger Lake rev: 1 cache: L1: 480 KiB L2: 7.5 MiB L3: 12 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1278 high: 3623 min/max: 800/4400 cores: 1: 1238 2: 801
    3: 800 4: 800 5: 800 6: 800 7: 3623 8: 800 9: 800 10: 800 11: 800 12: 3281
    bogomips: 62668
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel TigerLake-H GT1 [UHD Graphics] vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    driver: i915 v: kernel arch: Gen-12.1 ports: active: eDP-1 empty: DP-1
    bus-ID: 0000:00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:9a68
  Device-2: NVIDIA TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q]
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: nouveau v: kernel arch: Turing ports:
    active: HDMI-A-1 empty: none bus-ID: 0000:01:00.0 chip-ID: 10de:1f9d
  Device-3: Chicony HP Wide Vision HD Camera driver: uvcvideo type: USB
    rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 3-6:4 chip-ID: 04f2:b735
  Display: wayland server: X.org v: 1.20.14 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.4
    compositor: kwin_wayland driver: X: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa
    dri: iris,nouveau gpu: i915,nouveau d-rect: 3840x1080 display-ID: 0
  Monitor-1: HDMI-A-1 pos: primary,left res: 1920x1080 size: N/A
  Monitor-2: eDP-1 pos: right res: 1920x1080 size: N/A
  API: EGL v: 1.5 platforms: device: 0 drv: iris device: 1 drv: nouveau
    device: 2 drv: swrast gbm: drv: nouveau surfaceless: drv: iris wayland:
    drv: iris x11: drv: iris
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 compat-v: 4.3 vendor: intel mesa v: 23.3.6 glx-v: 1.4
    direct-render: yes renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (TGL GT1)
    device-ID: 8086:9a68 display-ID: :0.0
  API: Vulkan v: 1.3.275 surfaces: xcb,xlib,wayland device: 0
    type: integrated-gpu driver: N/A device-ID: 8086:9a68 device: 1 type: cpu
    driver: N/A device-ID: 10005:0000
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake-H HD Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl bus-ID: 0000:00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:43c8
  Device-2: NVIDIA vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel
    bus-ID: 0000:01:00.1 chip-ID: 10de:10fa
  Device-3: JMTek LLC. USB PnP Audio Device
    driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid type: USB rev: 1.1 speed: 12 Mb/s
    lanes: 1 bus-ID: 3-2:3 chip-ID: 0c76:1612
  API: ALSA v: k6.8.4-200.fc39.x86_64 status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.4 status: active with: 1: pipewire-pulse
    status: active 2: wireplumber status: active 3: pipewire-alsa type: plugin
    4: pw-jack type: plugin
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake PCH CNVi WiFi driver: iwlwifi v: kernel
    bus-ID: 0000:00:14.3 chip-ID: 8086:43f0
  IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 3000
    bus-ID: 0000:02:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8168
  IF: eno1 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel AX201 Bluetooth driver: btusb v: 0.8 type: USB rev: 2.0
    speed: 12 Mb/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 3-14:5 chip-ID: 8087:0026
  Report: btmgmt ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter> bt-v: 5.2
    lmp-v: 11
RAID:
  Hardware-1: Intel Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller driver: vmd
    v: 0.6 bus-ID: 0000:00:0e.0 chip-ID: 8086:9a0b
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 942.7 GiB used: 152.84 GiB (16.2%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZVL2512HCJQ-00BH1
    size: 476.94 GiB speed: 63.2 Gb/s lanes: 4 serial: <filter> temp: 46.9 C
  ID-2: /dev/nvme1n1 vendor: Kingston model: SNVS500G size: 465.76 GiB
    speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 serial: <filter> temp: 50.9 C
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 220.36 GiB used: 38.12 GiB (17.3%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme1n1p5
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 974.6 MiB used: 19 MiB (2.0%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme1n1p3
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: zram size: 8 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: 100
    dev: /dev/zram0
  ID-2: swap-2 type: partition size: 7.45 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%)
    priority: -2 dev: /dev/nvme1n1p4
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 55.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (rpm): N/A
Info:
  Memory: total: 16 GiB note: est. available: 15.25 GiB used: 5.93 GiB (38.9%)
  Processes: 359 Power: uptime: 16m wakeups: 0 Init: systemd v: 254
    target: graphical (5) default: graphical
  Packages: pm: flatpak pkgs: 20 Compilers: gcc: 13.2.1 Shell: Bash
    v: 5.2.26 running-in: yakuake inxi: 3.3.33

This is the output of the command ifconfig.
eno1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 50:81:40:72:c9:59  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 14  bytes 1810 (1.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 14  bytes 1810 (1.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.191  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::f5c6:b987:8f97:46b7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 38:87:d5:13:9b:ba  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 26444  bytes 20550511 (19.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17566  bytes 4356336 (4.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

For probable solutions, I have tried the following two.
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=8
And
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8"| sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlopts.conf
Applying this, I saw a temporary increase in the speed. However, it went down again this afternoon.
What could be done to resolve this issue?

If you use another adapter on your PC, then you have to post more information of ifconfig

@PICOPress, added. Please check.

If your SSID is broadcasted in both the 2.4GHz and 5GHz ranges, when you're experiencing slow speeds, check the output of $ iw dev wlo1 link. Check that that freq is in the 5GHz spectrum, and also make sure you have a decent rx bitrate and tx bitrate.
If everything looks good, try turning off the power save feature that is enabled by default on Intel WiFi chipsets. Check current status with
$ iw dev wlo1 get power_save
Power save: on

and turn it off with
$ sudo iw dev wlo1 set power_save off
$ iw dev wlo1 get power_save
Power save: off


What relevance does this have to the power-saving mode? Could you elaborate?

Power saving mode increases average latency and decreases performance overall. It is worth a shot to see if it makes a difference in your case.
